# How can I execute saved query statement in table in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

```
INSERT @Table
SELECT 'A','DECLARE @C INT = 1 SELECT @C+1'
UNION
SELECT 'B','DECLARE @C INT = 5 SELECT @C+6'

SELECT *
FROM   @Table
```

Comment: Can you explain what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: Take look at Exec command or execute

Comment: you can use execute or sp_executesql  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-executesql-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017

Comment: not clear, please show some data and the desired output

Comment: I want to execute query statement that saved in table with other columns of table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want to run column **B** query..

```
declare @Table as table(a varchar(100),b varchar(500))

INSERT @Table
SELECT 'A','DECLARE @C INT = 1 SELECT @C+1'
UNION
SELECT 'B','DECLARE @C INT = 5 SELECT @C+6'


DECLARE @VAR VARCHAR(500)
SET @VAR=(SELECT B FROM @Table WHERE A='A')

PRINT @VAR
EXEC (@VAR)
```

Comment: my table have 66500 rows and I should show all column.

Comment: @samiramahdavi use loop

Comment: You can use loop or create single statement from table then execute.

Comment: You can use loop or create single statement from table then execute.

Answer (score 1):

So you are trying to store the queries in your table and then dynamically call them based on some conditions. then you would want to execute those queries. the below code must work.

```
create table #table (
rowcnt int identity (1,1),
value1 varchar(10), 
query1 varchar(8000))

declare @query varchar(8000);

INSERT @Table
SELECT 'A','DECLARE @C INT = 1 SELECT @C+1'
UNION
SELECT 'B','DECLARE @C INT = 5 SELECT @C+6'

select @query = query1 from #table where id =1

exec (@query)
```

Please note storing scripts in tables and then calling them is not a good practices.
As if the Stored procedure which will call this scripts ever hit any problems it would be a nightmare for debugging it. Also it would be tough for performing performance optimization on DB.

Note if you would need to concat multiple rows for getting the full query use the below code

```
select @query = COALESCE(@query,'') +query1 from #table where id =1
```

Comment: I should use while statement for execute all rows!! this performance is so bad.  I have 66000 rows data!

Comment: With While you will introduce performance issues and i would suggest to avoid it at all cost. Looping is bad for SQl and it may even lead to deadlocks in DB. how frequently are you planning to execute this ?

Comment: give us some more info to help.
1. How is this table accessed (is it via a batch job, or an event, or anyother way)
2. Frequency of this while loop (do you execute daily, weekly or hourly)
3. Any constraints for it like job must complete its execution in 10mins, 30mins and so on
4. Do your DB has a DB team or do you have access to execution plan.

Comment: execution more than 20 mins and all user can call this query every day